# How to click a link within youtube comment using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to selenium python, I'm trying to click a link in the youtube comment but I don't know what element to use? Can someone help me? thanks . 
example :

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/redirect?event=comments&amp;redir_token=ttzJJRuKzz6sJPh8qdMnWStc-958MTU0NjE1NDU4M0AxNTQ2MDY4MTgz&amp;stzid=Ugw6ip_QkzwyJPIq3bp4AaABAg&amp;q=https%3A%2F%2Fjulissars.itworks.com%2F" rel="nofollow">https://julissars.itworks.com&#65279;</a>
```

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJezMYvf8Ss&lc=Ugw6ip_QkzwyJPIq3bp4AaABAg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the desired comment with text as `https://julissars.itworks.com` within the [url](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJezMYvf8Ss&lc=Ugw6ip_QkzwyJPIq3bp4AaABAg) you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "julissars"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string[href*='julissars']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string' and contains(., 'julissars')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: can you help me a little more ? @DebanjanB

Comment: @vantuong Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993925/how-to-click-a-link-within-youtube-comment-using-python-selenium-with-user-agent ! I created a new question here