# How to click youtube link within youtube comment using an user agent through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, user-agent, webdriverwait

I'm learning about python selenium, I want to click a youtube link in the youtube comment, can someone help me?

Example: [URL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&lc=UgwNBxYVXb6uiVTioPB4AaABAg)

Html :

```html
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/watch?v=PbLtyVcMrk0">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbLtyVcMrk0&#65279;</a>
```

Code trials :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ua = UserAgent()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument('user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&lc=UgwNBxYVXb6uiVTioPB4AaABAg")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='yt-uix-sessionlink  ' and contains(@href, '/watch?v=PbLtyVcMrk0')]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. To click on the desired comment with text as **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbLtyVcMrk0** within the [url](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&lc=UgwNBxYVXb6uiVTioPB4AaABAg) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution using useragent through Selenium and Python:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from fake_useragent import UserAgent
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  ua = UserAgent()
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  userAgent = ua.random
  print(userAgent)
  options.add_argument('user-agent=' + userAgent)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&lc=UgwNBxYVXb6uiVTioPB4AaABAg")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='yt-uix-sessionlink       spf-link ' and contains(@href, '/watch?v=PbLtyVcMrk0')]"))).click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your xpath, also the logic which you implemented to perform click operation could be more refined like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ua = UserAgent()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument('user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)    
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&lc=UgwNBxYVXb6uiVTioPB4AaABAg")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yt-formatted-string[class*='ytd-comment-renderer'][id='content-text']>a")))
clickLinks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("yt-formatted-string[class*='ytd-comment-renderer'][id='content-text']>a")
for element in clickLinks:
    if 'youtube' in element.text:
        element.click()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in id, I set it to '' / watch? v = PbLtyVcMrk0 '' but it doesn't work!
Thanks learner8269 very much, I have found the solution.