# How to use python selenium to click this element with text bb1

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, youtube, css-selectors

```
<yt-formatted-string id="channel-title" class="style-scope ytd-account-item-renderer">bb1</yt-formatted-string>
```

below one is a dangerous find element by full x path because the index might change

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/iron-dropdown/div/ytd-multi-page-menu-renderer/div[4]/ytd-multi-page-menu-renderer/div[3]/div[1]/ytd-account-section-list-renderer[1]/div/ytd-account-item-section-renderer/div/ytd-account-item-renderer[4]/paper-icon-item/paper-item-body/yt-formatted-string[1]').click()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click button by text using Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470171/click-button-by-text-using-python-and-selenium)

Comment: Why not just find by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **bb1** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-account-item-renderer#channel-title").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-account-item-renderer' and @id='channel-title'][text()='bb1']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-account-item-renderer#channel-title"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-account-item-renderer' and @id='channel-title'][text()='bb1']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click a link within youtube comment using python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968183/how-to-click-a-link-within-youtube-comment-using-python-selenium/53968323#53968323)